# How to apply operator precedence for calculator? Library? Is ANTLR the right library to use?

Tags: java, antlr, operator-precedence

I'm trying to make a calculator app which applies operator precedence.

However, I really haven't been able to find any clear references on how to apply it in Java. I understand that I will probably have to use a recursive descent parser (unless there's another method or better way to do this). If so, would it be better for me to code the parser myself? Or should I utilize a library.

While browsing the forums, I came upon an answer which suggested using ANTLR but I find that it seems to be for language grammar rather than applying operator precedence in expressions.

If it's better for me to code the recursive descent parser myself, could you please link me to some references on how to do so?

If I should use a library, could you please also link me to one with some examples as to how to apply operator precedence?

I'm not really sure how to apply ANTLR for operator precedence and I haven't seen any clear references in the docs either on how to apply it which leaves me with doubts as to whether or not this is the right library to use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you are mixing ANTLR with operator precedence. ANTLR is simply a parser (and lexer) generator. You could use Bison/Flex for the same result.

Now, precedence if given by the grammar itself (there might be some error, I've seen example doing `mult '+' mult`):

```
expr: mult '+' expr
    | mult '-' expr
    | mult
    ;

mult: atom '*' mult
    | atom '/' mult
    | atom
    ;

atom: T_NUMBER
    | '(' expr ')'
    ;
```

This grammar almost map naturally to Java code: each rules is a function getting the next token, and so on.

For example, the expression 1 + 2 * 7 will do:

```
rule expr:
  read token '1' (from rule atom)
  read '+' read a new expr
    read '2' (from rule atom)
    read '*' -> will use rule 'mult'.
      read '7' (rule atom).

-> 1 + ( (2) * (7))
```

I can't explain you the logic behind that, for I learned that in France 9 years ago, and I don't really need parser/lexer.

Comment: I was browsing the forums on how to apply operator precedence and one of the answers suggested using ANTLR. That's the reason why I wasn't sure if it was the right one to use or not.If not ANTLR, what library should I use to apply operator precedence?

Comment: That's not a matter of library, but more of understanding how to enforce operator precedence. ANTLR is _simply_ a parser generator: it does the job, but you will still have to write the grammar.